# Vs Code dont show node express request aliases

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I'm begginer, in the left it's mine Vs Code, in the right the example that I want. How can I enable it?

That will help me alot.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QQZY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @types/express` should solve it

you might need `npm install @types/node` as well

Comment: I installed and they are on devDependencies, but still no results.  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "github:types/express",
    "@types/node": "^18.6.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}

Comment: I installed another version of @types/express and it worked. Thank you!